# How to save very large results of dask merge directly to the file in python?

Tags: python, join, dask

I have a large file ~1 TB which I have to join with the smaller one ~4 GB.
I am trying to use dask package for this dask but result of merge is bigger than machine memory which is 128 GB and ending up with MemoryError. I am trying to keep results of merge as delayed collection but not sure how to save results directly to external file at the end.

```
small_file = dd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep='|', dtype=str)
large_file = dd.read_csv('file2.txt', sep='|', dtype=str)
merged = dd.merge(large_file, small_file, on='key').to_delayed()
```

Comment: Provide some information for your files and the process you wish to achieve? Presumably they are CSV but how do you intend to merge them? Simply one after the other or something different?

Comment: Two files with the same 2080 columns. All fields separated by |. I would like to join them using same field and take all fields at the end. What I want to achieve is joining small file to larger one and filter records down and output all variables at the end to external file.

Answer (score 0):

To save a dask dataframe to file you can use methods like `to_csv` or `to_parquet`

```
small_file = dd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep='|', dtype=str)
large_file = dd.read_csv('file2.txt', sep='|', dtype=str)
merged = dd.merge(large_file, small_file, on='key')
merged.to_csv('path/to/myfiles.*.csv')
```

See http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html for more information

Comment: Yeah, I know :) The problem is that merge itself can not fit into memory. What I figured out is loading this files in parts to memory and changing column types as default ones take a lot of memory. In such a case merge operation is pretty fast but... saving results to disk take unfortunately much time. But did not find anything better so far.